# How to convert string to numbers (if numeric), otherwise leave as string in SQL

Tags: sql, database

my column has customer numbers that are both numeric and combinations of text and numbers. I only want to convert them if they are all numeric otherwise leave them as a string

```
ex.
91036
ab321
10001
```

Only convert `91036` and `10001` as numbers (using cast or convert) but leave ab321 as string. I tried isnumeric but this isn't a recognized function in the query builder I'm using. And if I convert using cast or convert the strings are disappearing.

Comment: Please tag your question with used DBMS

Comment: Keep them all as strings. A column has a defined data type.

Comment: That's not to hard, but the problem is that if you want to return them in one column then that's impossible because the column must have one type and in this case it must be a string type, so after we convert the numbers, SQL will convert them back to strings and all our efforts go wasted. You'll have to return them in two different columns, is that OK?

Comment: if you tag your RDBMS, we could possibly say why `isnumeric` is not a recognised function.t-SQl:The ISNUMERIC function returns 1 = Number
The ISNUMERIC function returns 0 = text

Answer (score 0):

This is an example based on Oracle, but I believe that the same principle would work elsewhere (at least, in databases that support regular expressions).

I don't quite understand what you meant by saying that you want to "convert" those values to numbers; convert *where*? I presume that they are currently stored in a VARCHAR2 (or some other "character" datatype column). There's no use in converting them to number an leave them in the same column, as that wouldn't do absolutely anything - they would still be treated as *strings* (stored in the character datatype column, remember?).

So, I've created another - NUMBER datatype column and will populate it with a number whenever possible.

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test (col_char varchar2(10),
  2                     col_num  number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col_char)
  2    (select '91036' from dual union
  3     select 'ab321' from dual union
  4     select '10001' from dual
  5    );

3 rows created.
```

Update uses REGEXP_LIKE function which checks whether COL_CHAR looks like a number:

- `^` anchors you to the beginning of the string
- `\d+` takes as many consecutive digits as it can find
- `$` anchors you to the end of the string

which, all together, means that string must begin with a digit, must end with a digit, and everything in between have to be digits.

```
SQL> update test set
  2    col_num = to_number(col_char)
  3    where regexp_like(col_char, '^\d+$');

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * From test;

COL_CHAR      COL_NUM
---------- ----------
10001           10001
91036           91036
ab321

SQL>
```

Things are getting somewhat more complex when there are decimals and/or thousands separators in a string, so you might need to alter both TO_NUMBER function and regular expression pattern. For example:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    col_num = to_number(col_char, '999990D00000', 'nls_numeric_characters = '',.''')
  3    where regexp_like(col_char, '^[0-9]+|(\,)[0-9]+$');

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test;

COL_CHAR      COL_NUM
---------- ----------
10001           10001
91,036         91,036
ab321

SQL>
```